# Securing LTPA Token in WebSphere Liberty Profile

Tags: cookies, jax-rs, websphere-liberty, open-liberty, ltpa

We are using WebSphere Liberty Profile (17.0.0.4) to run our JAX-RS REST services. We are running our applications through Contrast, which is a scanning service. It is flagging our cookies as having the secure flag turned off. However, we are not using or touching any cookies in our code. The only cookie that is coming back in the response from our services is `LtpaToken2`, and sure enough, it has the secure flag set to `false`. How can I enable the secure flag for the `LtpaToken2` cookie (hopefully via configuration and not having to read and rewrite it in our code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `<webAppSecurity ssoRequiresSSL="true"/>` to the server.xml file should do it.

Comment: Thanks, Alaine, that did the trick.

Ironically, though, we were getting two different violations, but only one went away. But since only one cookie is being returned from our application, and it does have the secure flag on, we're going to ignore the other one.